# How to reset MatrixBox in EmguCv using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I've been unable to find much documentation for properly using the MatrixBox from the Emgu.CV.UI.

I'm using EmguCV version 3.4.1 and I would like to use the MatrixBox to show a live update of pixel values from a video I'm streaming.

[Winforms Matrixbox Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHMWG.png)

```
    private void BufferReceiver_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Matrix<UInt16> matrix = new Matrix<UInt16>(mat.Rows, mat.Cols, mat.NumberOfChannels);
        Matrix<UInt16> subMatrix = matrix.GetSubRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));

        matrixBox1.Matrix = subMatrix;
        matrixBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

I'm able to display a 10x10 matrix of the pixel values, but when the above method executes again, the matrix grows to 20x20, but replaces the 10x10 matrix with the updated values.

[First Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ns0z.png)

[Second Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DymLW.png)

I can see from the OpenCv source that the MatrixBox is just updating a DataGridView, but I can't find a way to clear the MatrixBox before updating the values.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
    Size sz = matrixBox1.Size;
    Point lc = matrixBox1.Location;
    int ti = matrixBox1.TabIndex;
    matrixBox1.Dispose();
    matrixBox1 = New Emgu.CV.UI.MatrixBox;
    matrixBox1.Parent = this;
    matrixBox1.Location = lc;
    matrixBox1.Matrix = Nothing;
    matrixBox1.Name = "MatrixBox1";
    matrixBox1.Size = sz;
    matrixBox1.TabIndex = ti;

    matrixBox1.Matrix = subMatrix;
```